# Calling Armadillo function in OpenMP parallel for loop causes data corruption

Tags: c++, openmp, armadillo

I'm trying to parallelise a large linear system solve using Armadillo and OpenMP using `arma::solve`. Instead of directly calling the solver I would like to split the problems into smaller chunks of RHS vectors and call them in parallel in an OpenMP loop as shown in the Listing below.

This should result in the same answer since the multiple RHS are independent problems but I often get a few columns mangled when I run the code in this manner. I've even tried to enclose the write back in an `omp critical` section but it still fails.

Is Armadillo safe to run in this manner or am I missing something here?

```
// to compile the code run as
// g++ parals.cpp -I$ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR  -L$ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR/../lib64
//  -larmadillo -fopenmp -lopenblas -o parals.out
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#define ARMA_USE_BLAS
#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK

#include <armadillo>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace arma;

/*
 * Solves LS for a single problem,
 *
 * ||AX - B ||_F^2
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int m = atoi(argv[1]);     // A is of size m \times n
  int n = atoi(argv[2]);     // A is of size m \times n
  int k = atoi(argv[3]);     // B is of size m \times k
  int seed = atoi(argv[4]);  // seed for random inits
  int chunk = atoi(argv[5]); // chunk size to group RHS

  arma::arma_rng::set_seed(seed);

  std::cout << "m::" << m << "::n::" << n << "::k::" << k
            << "::seed::" << seed << "::chunk::" << chunk
            << std::endl;

  mat A(m,n,arma::fill::randu);
  //std::cout << "A::" << std::endl << A << std::endl;

  mat B(m,k,arma::fill::randu);
  //std::cout << "B::" << std::endl << B << std::endl;

  mat AtA = A.t() * A;
  mat AtB = A.t() * B;
 
  // solve sequentially 
  mat Xseq = arma::solve(AtA, AtB, arma::solve_opts::likely_sympd);

 
  int num_chunks = AtB.n_cols / chunk;
  if (num_chunks * chunk < AtB.n_cols) num_chunks++; 

  mat Xchunk(n,k,arma::fill::zeros);

  for (int nt = 0; nt < num_chunks; nt++) {
    int spanStart = nt * chunk;
    int spanEnd = (nt + 1) * chunk - 1;
    if (spanEnd > AtB.n_cols - 1) {
      spanEnd = AtB.n_cols - 1;
    }

    mat rhs = AtB.cols(spanStart, spanEnd);
    mat Y = arma::solve(AtA, rhs, arma::solve_opts::likely_sympd);

    Xchunk.cols(spanStart, spanEnd) = Y;
  }
  
  bool chkchunk = arma::approx_equal(Xseq, Xchunk, "absdiff", 0.0001);
  std::cout << "(Xseq == Xchunk) ? = " << chkchunk << std::endl;
  
  if (!chkchunk) {
    std::cout << "Xseq::" << std::endl << Xseq << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Xchunk::" << std::endl << Xchunk << std::endl;
  }

  mat Xpar(n,k,arma::fill::zeros);

  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
  for (int nt = 0; nt < num_chunks; nt++) {
    int spanStart = nt * chunk;
    int spanEnd = (nt + 1) * chunk - 1;
    if (spanEnd > AtB.n_cols - 1) {
      spanEnd = AtB.n_cols - 1;
    }

    mat rhs = AtB.cols(spanStart, spanEnd);
    mat Y = arma::solve(AtA, rhs, arma::solve_opts::likely_sympd);

    Xpar.cols(spanStart, spanEnd) = Y;
  }
  

  bool chkpar = arma::approx_equal(Xseq, Xpar, "absdiff", 0.0001);
  std::cout << "(Xseq == Xpar) ? = " << chkpar << std::endl;
  
  if (!chkpar) {
    std::cout << "Xseq::" << std::endl << Xseq << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Xpar::" << std::endl << Xpar << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

A small driver script to hopefully reproduce my errors. My Armadillo instance is linked with OpenBLAS and I don't specify the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}
do
  echo $i
  unset OMP_NUM_THREADS;
  ./parals.out 10 5 20 17 3
done
```

Comment: You have to be careful because depending on which libraries you are using to provide BLAS for armadillo it might or might not be thread-safe.

Search here in stackoverflow for "armadillo thread".

Comment: You're right. OpenBLAS is not thread safe unless you compile with [locking on](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq#multi-threaded).

Comment: If you are interested, check [this repository](https://github.com/darcamo/test_multithread_openblas) for code you can use to check if you have multithread problems in armadillo with the linked BLAS library. Basically, it defined a function that performs some matrix multiplications and SVDs and checks if there is any difference when running this function in parallel compared to serial. You probably need to change the `CMakeLists.txt` file.